# The problem with the query

Tags: php, postgresql

I can not find an answer to why this query does not work:

```
$query = pg_query($connect, sprintf("INSERT INTO table (uid, urzid, time_start, time_stop2, date_start, date_stop, cycle) VALUES ($uid, $pom, '$time1', '$time2', '$data1', '$data2', $cykl)"));
```

I get a warning: PG_QUERY() [FUNCTION.PG-QUERY]: QUERY FAILED: ERROR: SYNTAX ERROR AT OR NEAR "," AT CHARACTER 96

It seems to me that the error is associated with.'' $ time1, $ Time2 and $ date1, $ date2 are in accordance with the format for date and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot guess what content is in your variables.
Please run this code and paste the result:

```
echo "INSERT INTO table (uid, urzid, time_start, time_stop2, date_start, date_stop, cycle) VALUES ($uid, $pom, '$time1', '$time2', '$data1', '$data2', $cykl)";
```

You will find the syntax error.

The best way to avoid this kind of errors (and, even more importantly, to prevent [SQL injection](http://php.net/security.database.sql-injection)), is to use a library such as [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) and to use [placeholders](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) for variables.

**Update**: now that we could see what your variables look like, try this:

```
$query = pg_query($connect, "INSERT INTO table (uid, urzid, time_start, time_stop2, date_start, date_stop, cycle) VALUES ('$uid', '$pom', '$time1', '$time2', '$data1', '$data2', '$cykl')");
```

Don't forget to have a look at the above comment for best practices, however.

Comment: INSERT INTO REZERWACJE_URZ (UID, URZID, time_start, time_stop, date_start, date_stop, cycle) VALUES (, 7, '8:00', '9:30', '2011-06-09', '2011-06-09', 1)

Comment: Ok so $uid is an empty string, resulting in `, 7, ...`

Comment: Unfortunately it's not. After completing the uid I get the same warning.

Comment: @Mateusz Don't forget that variables in double quoted string works with simple variable like `$foo`, class attributes like `$foo->bar`, but **not** with arrays like `$foo['bar']`. You'll have to concatenate in this case `"SELECT ".$foo['bar']." FROM my_table"`.

Comment: I would be surprised that this query doesn't work. Please paste the string of the new query.

Comment: This query works: $query = pg_query($connect, "INSERT INTO table (uid, urzid, time_start, time_stop2, date_start, date_stop, cycle) VALUES ('$uid', '$pom', '$time1', '$time2', '$data1', '$data2', '$cykl')");

Comment: Thank you all for your help and valuable links.

Answer (score 5):

You have to provide a format to the function `sprintf`

See the [doc](http://php.net/function.sprintf)

And moreover, there's no needs at all of sprintf in this case.

Comment: +1, `sprintf()` is useless in the way you're using it. Either use it correctly, and escape your variables manually, or again use modern tools like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing quoting, " => ', " => ' ... saves me a lot pain always.

Comment: and escape your variables however you can ;)

Comment: That would both prevent his variables from being interpolated, and further break the query. What did you *think* it would accomplish?

Comment: nvm on the interpolation of variables, set them manualy with string concatenation ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add extra parameters :

```
$world = "World";
$foo = sprintf("Hello %s", $world);
```

However, as you are in a double quoted string you don't need sprintf :

```
$foo = "Hello $world";
```